# use some codepen scripts with visual composer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to use gradient animated background CodePen Script on my wordpress site using visual composer.

```js
var colors = new Array(
  [62,35,255],
  [60,255,60],
  [255,35,98],
  [45,175,230],
  [255,0,255],
  [255,128,0]);

var step = 0;
//color table indices for: 
// current color left
// next color left
// current color right
// next color right
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

//transition speed
var gradientSpeed = 0.002;

function updateGradient()
{
  
  if ( $===undefined ) return;
  
var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

var istep = 1 - step;
var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
var color1 = "rgb("+r1+","+g1+","+b1+")";

var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
var color2 = "rgb("+r2+","+g2+","+b2+")";

 $('#gradient').css({
   background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
    background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});
  
  step += gradientSpeed;
  if ( step >= 1 )
  {
    step %= 1;
    colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
    colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];
    
    //pick two new target color indices
    //do not pick the same as the current one
    colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    
  }
}

setInterval(updateGradient,10);
```

```css
.gradient{
   background-color: #ffffff;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
 }

#gradient
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 800vh;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gradient" />
 </body>
</html>
```

I already did:
1- create raw js element for JS section
2- create raw html element for html section (also tried with footer widget)
3- add css to Post settings
4- create empty row with "gradient" ID and Class

code works but the result is Fixed gradient Background, it's not changing colors.
and also don't have any warnings or errors in dev-tool console.

Comment: The code works fine for me and it's change the gradient color at the interval fine. In which browser you got an issue

Comment: `if ( $===undefined ) return;` when i debug in console $ is always undefined.

Comment: can you put your code in `$(document).ready(function() { //inside your code }`

Comment: in you script code, replace `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: Replace `if ( $===undefined ) return;` to `if ( jQuery===undefined ) return;` and `$('#gradient').css({` to `jQuery('#gradient').css({`

Comment: thank you, replacing  JQuery worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$` symbol to `jQuery`

```js
var colors = new Array(
  [62,35,255],
  [60,255,60],
  [255,35,98],
  [45,175,230],
  [255,0,255],
  [255,128,0]);

var step = 0;
//color table indices for: 
// current color left
// next color left
// current color right
// next color right
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

//transition speed
var gradientSpeed = 0.002;

function updateGradient()
{
  
  if ( jQuery===undefined ) return;
  
var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

var istep = 1 - step;
var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
var color1 = "rgb("+r1+","+g1+","+b1+")";

var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
var color2 = "rgb("+r2+","+g2+","+b2+")";

 jQuery('#gradient').css({
   background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
    background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});
  
  step += gradientSpeed;
  if ( step >= 1 )
  {
    step %= 1;
    colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
    colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];
    
    //pick two new target color indices
    //do not pick the same as the current one
    colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    
  }
}

setInterval(updateGradient,10);
```

```css
.gradient{
   background-color: #ffffff;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
 }

#gradient
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 800vh;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gradient" />
 </body>
</html>
```